# Get line by legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any convenient way to get the color of a line when I know the label?

Right now I'm doing

```
    color = None
    for l in ax.lines:
        if l.get_label() == myLabel:
            color = l.get_color()
            break

    else:
        raise Exception('not found')
```

which doesn't appear quite pythonic.

Comment: You can try and keep a dictionary `{'label':line}` updated each time you draw a new line, but what you have seems more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better, but still doesn't look that great: Use the legends label list:

```
ax.lines[ax.get_legend_handles_labels()[1].index(myLabel)].get_color()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
color = next((l.get_color() for l in ax.lines if l.get_label() == myLabel), None)
```